# Copying contents on a variable filename in shell scripting

Tags: shell

Hi I wanted to copy the /var/log/messages for 20 iterations. And the files for 20 iterations have to be saved separately. I have given the file name as below. Bu this command is not accepted and throws the below error.

```
 cp /var/log/messages > bug_iteration_$i
```

cp: missing destination file operand after `/var/log/messages'
Try`cp --help' for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wanted probably is

```
cp /var/log/messages "bug_iteration_$i"
```

Or

```
cat /var/log/messages > "bug_iteration_$i"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `cp` command takes two filenames, not one.  Either you need to use `cat` instead of `cp`, or (more likely) you should remove the `>` to just pass the second filename directly to `cp`.